# Генерация изображений

Tags: изображения

Мне надо сделать сервис который будет генерировать изображения и отдавать их по апи. Изображения - сертификаты для разных мероприятий. Т.е. на них должен быть текст (типа имени победителя) и простенькое оформление. Идеально если бы это можно было описать в HTML (как вьюху) и превратить потом как-то динамически в изображение нужного размера с нужным текстом. Посоветуйте что для этого можно использовать? Язык не принципиален, но подумываю может на Go сделать из-за быстродействия. Хотя картинки эти будут генерироваться не очень часто, но запрашивать буду с разных сервисов.

P.S. Вручную рисовать через API библиотеки (типа [этого](https://4gophers.ru/articles/rabota-s-izobrazheniyami/#.VUzNcSftlBc)) не очень хотелось бы.

Comment: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: @norbornen Это же вроде только для пдф? А мне изображения надо (png или jpg). К тому же важно не просто хтмл голый перегонять, а чтобы переменные туда можно было подставить как в реальную вьюху.

Comment: сорян, вспомнил свою задачку и не внимательно прочёл вопрос. я бы сделал сервис, который генерирует готовый html (так или иначе, что ж тут сложного), с сервиса получал бы сгенерированный html и с помощью тематических либ генерировал из него jpg.

Comment: по опыту сертификатики/билетики/грамоты как раз лучше в pdf-е отдавать

Comment: @norbornen Так что за тематические либы то? В этом и заключался вопрос вообще-то. А сертификаты у нас тут везде картинкой отдаются. Тут еще дело в том что эти сертификаты отображаются на сайте. Т.е. рендерятся как картинка (тегом img). А если они будут пдфкой то так не выйдет сделать.

Comment: а гугл на что? вот тут третья ссылка https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=sYodWoruL-mC6QTBhqbwBA&q=golang+how+to+convert+html+to+jpeg&oq=golang+how+to+convert+html+to+jpeg&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10311.11707.0.12028.4.4.0.0.0.0.66.233.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Jr_WD_VqZHM

Comment: хинт: в запросе можно менять наименование языка